# Sequence Diagrams with Statemachines

Tags: state-machine, enterprise-architect, simulate, sequence-diagram

I would like to understand how sequence diagrams can correspond state-machines:

In sequence diagrams you show the message exchange between objects: EA allows only to show operations.
In EA StateMachines you have to use triggers.
But the triggers cannot be used in Sequence Diagrams!

How do these concepts play together?

Answer (score 2):

See [State Invariant](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html).

You can also place Triggers and State Machines directly on SDs.

[image]

Here the state machine has an `EntryPoint` *State Entry* which is signaled by *Class1*. The `Trigger` is connected with *Class1*'s *triggerOp()* (this recursive example is just an example and does not make much sense). The `StateInvariant` shows that *Class1* is in state *State1*.